# How to use EF sharing same DbContext for multiple databases

Tags: c#, entity-framework, autofac

I am having a multitenant application which uses same web app with multiple Customer databases and having shared DbContext. When user logs in based on his credentials I provide connection string to DbContext and load the data. Problem occurs when multiple user logs in at the same time and they can see each others data as DbContext keeps on switching between different users.

I am using EF 5.0 and Autofac IOC mainly. Whats the best way to manage this?

How can I have my DbContext maintain its data for that specific user and will not change even though other users logged in and will have different database contexts for them?

Here's code in my Login page,

```
protected void LoginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(CustomerId.Text);
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            var profile = _profileProvider.GetCustomerProfile(i);
            ConnectionStringManager.ConnectionString = profile.connString;
            builder.RegisterModule<CustomerDataModule>();
            builder.Update(_container);
            Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
     }
```

This is my static variable which gives connection string

```
public static class ConnectionStringManager
{
    public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my Module which has all entities and context classes,

```
public class CustomerDataModule : Autofac.Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register(c =>
        {
            ConnectionString = ConnectionStringManager.ConnectionString;

            return new CustomerDataContext(ConnectionString);
        })
        .As<ICustomerDataContext>()
        .As<IDbContext>()
        .InstancePerDependency();

        builder.RegisterType<CustomerDataContextFactory>().As<ICustomerDataContextFactory>();

        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
               .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
               .AsImplementedInterfaces()
               .InstancePerDependency();

    }
}
```

Here's my DbContext,

```
public partial class CustomerDataContext: DbContext, ICustomerDataContext
{ 

    public CustomerDataContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    { }
    .......
```

Here's my One of the repository,

```
public class CustomerRepository : GenericRepository<Customer, int>, ICustomerRepository
{
    public CustomerRepository(ICustomerDataContext context)
        : base(context, customer => customer.Id)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you explored the multi-tenancy extensions to Autofac, Autofac.Extras.Multitenant.dll?  See http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MultitenantIntegration.  At the very least, there is no way that you can set the connection string in a static variable, it needs to be derived from the container itself, based on the user context of the request.

Comment: I am little new to autofac, I will definitely go and explore multi-tenancy extensions. Can you show me small code snippet to derive it from Container based on user context to avoid static variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a static variable in a web app means sharing its data between all users at the same time. you need to move that value to a session variable, which is specific to each user.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
// will add `HTTP request lifetime scoped` registrations (InstancePerHttpRequest) for the HTTP abstraction classes
builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule()); 
builder.Register<MyType>(ctx =>
    {
        var sessionBase = ctx.Resolve<HttpSessionStateBase>();
        //now use the session value to retrieve the connection string
    });
```

Comment: One more thing, I am registering my CustomerDataModule at login button click and that sounds little odd to me. As we do this usually at app start up. But I don't see any other option available as I don't have user profile to get his tenant details. Can you advice any better options or improvements in this code?

Comment: You can move it to Application_Start: http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WebFormsIntegration

Comment: But how will I know the tenant Id if I put it in Application_start. I will need user to login ..which will happen after Application_start. Once user logs in then I can get specific connection string which belongs to his tenant database.

Comment: Store that value in a Session variable, then use `ctx.Resolve<HttpSessionStateBase>();` to access it later in the registration module (like the above mentioned code). Change the life time of the component to `InstancePerHttpRequest`. it will resolve the session at beginning of each request automatically. Also don't forget to register `AutofacWebTypesModule`.

Comment: Got it! Also, do I need to register all my other modules (e.g Service modules, Data modules, logging modules etc.) also as InstancePerHttpRequest?